# WCF services Communication Exception

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, soap, service

I am trying to access a WCF service from my mvc website, that I created in a service library, but I keep getting a communication exception, this method is supposed to return just one row from the database and therefore I don't believe that its a memory problem, I managed to use this service to perform an insert to the database but any retrieval method is failing.

My code may be found below.

UserService

```
IEnumerable<COUNTRY> IUserService.getCountries()
{
    return new UsersRepository().getCountries();
}
```

IUserService

```
[OperationContract]
IEnumerable<COUNTRY> getCountries();
```

Service Web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DSAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOODED;initial catalog=DSA;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Website webconfig

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxArrayLength="200000000"
          maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50004/UserService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" contract="UserReference.IUserService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My code

```
 public UserReference.UserServiceClient client = new UserReference.UserServiceClient();
   IEnumerable<ROLE> roles = client.getRoles();
```

Comment: Since you activated includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" the server exception should be in there somewhere. Can you post more exception details, please? A CommunicationException can have lots of reasons in WCF.

Comment: In "My code" it says: IEnumerable<ROLE> roles = client.getRoles(); but the code you posted above says: IEnumerable<COUNTRY> getCountries(); Are you sure you are working with the right interface?

Answer (score 0):

Force the enumeration of the data before the data context is lost. 
Instead of

```
IEnumerable<COUNTRY> IUserService.getCountries()
{
    return new UsersRepository().getCountries();
}
```

do

```
IEnumerable<COUNTRY> IUserService.getCountries()
{
    return new UsersRepository().getCountries().ToList();
}
```